# NSPopUpButton, Bindings and a shortening lifespan

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am trying to come to grips with how difficult it is to use NSPopUpButton. It's by far and away the most difficult user element to program in Cocoa (at least as far as I am finding it).

The use case I have in mind is as follows:

- I have a class called Port that represents a Serial port.
- Amongst the attributes is a name field.
- In the NSPopUpButton I want to display the name field for each port.
- When a user selects a specific port it is marked in the pop-up with a tick as expected
- When the user subsequently hits a connect button I can ascertain which of the Ports from the Array was selected.
- I would like to achieve this using bindings as I think once I get my head around it, it will be the more elegant solution.

Therefore in my AppController.h I am expecting two attributes which I can presumably create as properties and synthesize:

```
NSMutableArray *allPorts;
Port *currentlySelectedPort;
```

and one action in my .m:

```
-(void)didSelectConnect:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Selected port name is:%@",[currentlySelectedPort name]);
}
```

in Port.h I have

```
NSString *name;
NSString *baudRate;
... etc ...
```

I have created a simple project which contains just a pop up (and a label) and following various articles, I have managed to populate an NSMutableArray with elements which I then use an ArrayController to display values and then on selection set the value of a label (using an object controller). However, as much as this is clever it doesn't fit the use case I am trying to implement. So I turn here for help

M

Comment: You might want to consider starting out without using bindings. You'll write more code, but it's imperative you understand that code (and all the underlying technologies behind bindings like KVO) before you can really make bindings work for you in complex examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, bindings with the `NSPopUpButton` are a bit complicated because there are two things it needs: a binding for the values, and a binding for which one of those values is selected. What makes it even more complicated is that there are a couple of perfectly legitimate ways of doing that, and which one you choose entirely depends on your program's structure and, to some extent, personal preferences.

So, in order to get a list of values, you bind the `content` property. In your case, you'd probably bind this to the `arrangedObjects` key of an `NSArrayController`. In this setup, each menu item represents one object. By default, the title of the menu item is the string returned by calling `description` on each item in the array. If you want to use a different property for the menu title, you can also bind the `contentValues` array. Just make sure the key path you specify for `contentValues` has the key path for `content` as its prefix (e.g. you might use `arrangedObjects` for `content` and `arrangedObjects.name` for `contentValues`)

This will give you menu items that represent objects. What you need next is some way of identifying the selected one. There are three different bindings you can use: `selectedIndex`, `selectedObject` and `selectedValue`. They represent, respectively, the index of the array object that the user selected, the object value (one of the objects in the `content` array), and the string title of the selected item (one of the objects in the `contentValues` array if you bound that property).

So, in your case, you might bind `selectedObject` to a `selectedSerialPort` property on your controller class. When the user clicks the "Connect" button, you only have to refer to the `selectedSerialPort` property.

Answer (score 6):

You can download a [sample Xcode project here](http://bitbucket.org/abizern/popup/get/tip.zip). This sticks as close as I could get to your description.

The important thing is to look at the connections between the array controller, the AppController and the popup box.

Basically, this just demonstrates what Alex said.

Comment: Abizem, I would love to accepts to answers as your code, with the explanation worked a treat!

Comment: What if you don't initialize your allPorts array until awakeFromNib? How would you tell NSPopUpButton to reload the values?